# Cucumber capybara fill_in failing

Tags: tdd, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I've been building a rails4 app and running through testing with cucumber and capybara but have hit a snag.  I'm doing standard testing for user creation and user edit.

The user create test ran through without any issue but upon running through the test for editing the user I can't get capybara to actually fill in the new values into the fields.  The form is the same for new and edit (I am including the same _form partial to both) and again it works fine on new but not edit.

Cucumber New User test:

```
When I fill in a User with:
  | First Name   | Rufus             |
  | Last Name    | Firefly           |
  | Email        | rfirefly@fake.com |
  | Role(S)      | System Admin      |
```

Cucumber Edit User test:

```
When I fill in a User with:
  | First Name   | Otis              |
  | Last Name    | Driftwood         |
  | Email        | otis@fake.com     |
```

Corresponding method:

```
When /^(?:|I) fill in (?:a|an|the) (.+) with:$/ do |obj, fields|
  attrs = {}
  fields.rows_hash.each do |name, value|
    fill_in(name, with: value) unless name =~ /\((?:R|S)\)$/
    choose(value) if name =~ /\(R\)$/
    select(value) if name =~ /\(S\)$/
  end
end
```

Rendered html form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/members/1" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /></div><div class='field'>
<label for="user_first_name">First Name</label>
<input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" type="text" value="Ronald" />
</div>
<div class='field'>
    <label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" type="text" value="Kornblow" />
</div>
<div class='field'>
    <label for="user_email">Email</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="kornblow@fake.com" />
</div>
<div class='field'>
    <label for="user_password">Password</label>
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" />
</div>

... omitted fields (not required) ...

<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update User" />
</form>
```

Any help or insight anyone could give me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

> ```
> When /^(?:|I) fill in (?:a|an|the) (.+) with:$/ do |obj, fields|
>   attrs = {}
>   fields.rows_hash.each do |name, value|
>     fill_in(name, with: value) unless name =~ /\((?:R|S)\)$/
>     choose(value) if name =~ /\(R\)$/
>     select(value) if name =~ /\(S\)$/
>   end
> end
> ```

here, the `fill_in(name, :value)` method normally automatically looks for the ID tag `id=name`, but here your names don't line up exactly as shown by your rendered HTML form.

> ```
> <div class='field'>
>     <label for="user_last_name">Last Name</label>
>     <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" type="text" value="Kornblow" />
> </div>
> ```

Try changing your cucumber test to:

> ```
> When I fill in a User with:
>   | user_first_name   | Otis              |
>   | user_last_name    | Driftwood         |
>   | user_email        | otis@fake.com     |
> ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I have seen and have been using the fill_in() method with the label text.  From what I understand fill_in() accepts id, name attribute or corresponding label text.  

I did find the solution to my issue and it appears it had not nothing to do with this...

Answer (score 0):

So I did find the issue and I'm not happy about the last hour and a half that I lost due to what I believe was the problem...

I was using a nice little debugging tool for capybara to render the page and show it in the browser and this was not displaying the updated fields like I said above, but when i ran click_button() these values were in fact being saved.

The issue I was *really* having was that Devise, in all its infinite wisdom, was saving the new email address to unconfirmed_email and keeping the old email until the user gets the email and confirms. Makes sense but it was the first time I apparently ran into this.

So in my test:

```
Given a "User" was updated with:
  | Last Name         | Driftwood     |
  | Email             | otis@fake.com |
```

the email attribute really wasn't 'otis@fake.com' and the test, as it always is (no matter how much I argue with it) was right. This user was not updated in with that email.  Changing this to:

```
Given a "User" was updated with:
  | Last Name         | Driftwood         |
  | Email             | kornblow@fake.com |
  | Unconfirmed Email | otis@fake.com     |
```

Solved the problem.  I'm still confused why I was not seeing the fill(ed)_in() values when I rendered the page out tho. Kinda led me barking up the wrong tree.

Oh well...

Thanks for your help and hope this helps others...